# Did PHP 8.1 break functionality of internal class SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, migration, php-8.1

While making a library, that uses PHP's SoapClient, compatible with PHP 8.1 I came across this issue:

All properties of SoapClient are now private when they where public before.
So things like getting the last soap fault (`$soapClient->__soap_fault`) is no longer possible. But most methods of SoapClient return null if there was a problem and the only way of knowing what went wrong is to get `__soap_fault` which is no longer accessible.

How should I be working with method `__doRequest` without having access to the properties of SoapClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at old `SoapClient` documentation, it seems that it was always an error to access the properties directly - for php7.2 e.g. `__soap_fault` wasn't documented at all, according to the wayback machine (see https://web.archive.org/web/20171211100753/https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)

The documentation states the following:

> On error, a call to a SOAP function can cause PHP to throw exceptions or return a SoapFault object if exceptions are disabled. To check if the function call failed to catch the SoapFault exceptions, check the result with is_soap_fault().

I'd say, make sure you have exceptions enabled (by passing `$options['exceptions'] => true` to the SoapClient constructor) and handle those in a `try/catch` accordingly.  If that doesn't help, a new question with a concrete error that isn't handled correctly may be more helpful.